# How to maintain author name per project in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have several projects at my computer and some is for personal and some is the companies, I need different author name for these projects.

Can I define different author name for different projects?

Comment: Where do you need the name exactly? In file header comments? If that is the case you can just go to Settings/Editor/File and Code Templates/Includes/File Header, switch to Project schema in the top right corner and change the file header to contain the name you wish to use in your project.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt , thank you, that's what i need, would you please post it to the answer area?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to set per project author name to be used in file headers, etc, you can do so via modification of Code templates.

1. Go to Settings/Editor/File and Code Templates/Includes/File Header
2. Switch to *Project* schema in the upper right corner
3. Modify the file header template to contain the name you wish to use

[image]

The file header is not used for all types of files though. So for instance for JavaScript you need to modify the JavaScript file template separately.